# calling values from dict and changing values in a list

Tags: python

I have a list of DNA sequences like this:
very small example:

```
> seq = ['ATGGCGGCGCGA', 'GCCTCTGCCTTG', 'CTGAAAACG']
```

and if you divide the number of characters in each sequence by 3 you would get even number. 
I also have this dictionary which is codons and amino acids.

```
gencode = {
        'ATA':'I', 'ATC':'I', 'ATT':'I', 'ATG':'M', 'ACA':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACG':'T', 'ACT':'T',
        'AAC':'N', 'AAT':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K', 'AGC':'S', 'AGT':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R',
        'CTA':'L', 'CTC':'L', 'CTG':'L', 'CTT':'L', 'CCA':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCG':'P', 'CCT':'P',
        'CAC':'H', 'CAT':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q', 'CGA':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGG':'R', 'CGT':'R',
        'GTA':'V', 'GTC':'V', 'GTG':'V', 'GTT':'V', 'GCA':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCG':'A', 'GCT':'A',
        'GAC':'D', 'GAT':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E', 'GGA':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGG':'G', 'GGT':'G',
        'TCA':'S', 'TCC':'S', 'TCG':'S', 'TCT':'S', 'TTC':'F', 'TTT':'F', 'TTA':'L', 'TTG':'L',
        'TAC':'Y', 'TAT':'Y', 'TAA':'_', 'TAG':'_', 'TGC':'C', 'TGT':'C', 'TGA':'_', 'TGG':'W'}
```

I want replace each codn (3 characters) with its amino acid(its value in the above dictionary).
the results for the small example would be like this:

```
AA : ['MAAR', 'ASAL', 'LKT']
```

do you guys know how to do that?

Comment: Have you looked at BioPython? It will do what you are asking, plus much more. It is well tested and validated as well, which is probably more than most home-brew code will be.

Comment: Agree with Andrew, there is [Bio.SeqUtils.six_frame_translations](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/api/Bio.SeqUtils-module.html#six_frame_translations) that will do it for all reading frames...

Answer (score 2):

You can do one liner with list comprehension:

```
seq = ['ATGGCGGCGCGA', 'GCCTCTGCCTTG', 'CTGAAAACG']
gencode = {
        'ATA':'I', 'ATC':'I', 'ATT':'I', 'ATG':'M', 'ACA':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACG':'T', 'ACT':'T',
        'AAC':'N', 'AAT':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K', 'AGC':'S', 'AGT':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R',
        'CTA':'L', 'CTC':'L', 'CTG':'L', 'CTT':'L', 'CCA':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCG':'P', 'CCT':'P',
        'CAC':'H', 'CAT':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q', 'CGA':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGG':'R', 'CGT':'R',
        'GTA':'V', 'GTC':'V', 'GTG':'V', 'GTT':'V', 'GCA':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCG':'A', 'GCT':'A',
        'GAC':'D', 'GAT':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E', 'GGA':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGG':'G', 'GGT':'G',
        'TCA':'S', 'TCC':'S', 'TCG':'S', 'TCT':'S', 'TTC':'F', 'TTT':'F', 'TTA':'L', 'TTG':'L',
        'TAC':'Y', 'TAT':'Y', 'TAA':'_', 'TAG':'_', 'TGC':'C', 'TGT':'C', 'TGA':'_', 'TGG':'W'}

res = [''.join(gencode[s[i:i+3]] for i in range(0, len(s), 3)) for s in seq]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
['MAAR', 'ASAL', 'LKT']
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure (maybe there's a more pythonic way of doing that but that is simple and works):

```
seq = ['ATGGCGGCGCGA', 'GCCTCTGCCTTG', 'CTGAAAACG']
gencode = {
        'ATA':'I', 'ATC':'I', 'ATT':'I', 'ATG':'M', 'ACA':'T', 'ACC':'T', 'ACG':'T', 'ACT':'T',
        'AAC':'N', 'AAT':'N', 'AAA':'K', 'AAG':'K', 'AGC':'S', 'AGT':'S', 'AGA':'R', 'AGG':'R',
        'CTA':'L', 'CTC':'L', 'CTG':'L', 'CTT':'L', 'CCA':'P', 'CCC':'P', 'CCG':'P', 'CCT':'P',
        'CAC':'H', 'CAT':'H', 'CAA':'Q', 'CAG':'Q', 'CGA':'R', 'CGC':'R', 'CGG':'R', 'CGT':'R',
        'GTA':'V', 'GTC':'V', 'GTG':'V', 'GTT':'V', 'GCA':'A', 'GCC':'A', 'GCG':'A', 'GCT':'A',
        'GAC':'D', 'GAT':'D', 'GAA':'E', 'GAG':'E', 'GGA':'G', 'GGC':'G', 'GGG':'G', 'GGT':'G',
        'TCA':'S', 'TCC':'S', 'TCG':'S', 'TCT':'S', 'TTC':'F', 'TTT':'F', 'TTA':'L', 'TTG':'L',
        'TAC':'Y', 'TAT':'Y', 'TAA':'_', 'TAG':'_', 'TGC':'C', 'TGT':'C', 'TGA':'_', 'TGG':'W'}

total_result = []
for s in seq:  # for each item
    # listcomp to decompose & create char list
    result = [gencode[s[i:i+3]] for i in range(0,len(s),3)]
    total_result.append("".join(result))  # append as string

print(total_result)
```

result:

```
['MAAR', 'ASAL', 'LKT']
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a helper generator to split an iterable into chunks of length 3:

```
def chunks(xs, n):
    for i in range(0, len(xs), n):
        yield xs[i:i + n]
```

Replace each chunk with its corresponding amino acid and group them back together:

```
result = [''.join(gencode[c] for c in chunks(s, 3)) for s in seq]
```

This yields:

```
In [1]: result
Out[1]: ['MAAR', 'ASAL', 'LKT']
```